# register collectionViewCell Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to use a custom CollectionView Cell and for some reason, my app is crashing with the error,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I have the collection view set as

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! profCell
   let myColor = GREEN_Theme

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
   cell.layer.borderColor = myColor.cgColor
   cell.layer.cornerRadius = 10
   cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
   cell.textField.textColor = GREEN_Theme
   cell.textField.text = "Skills & Preferences"

    } else if indexPath.row == 1  {
         cell.backgroundColor = .yellow

    } else if indexPath.row == 2  {
        cell.backgroundColor = .red

    }

    return cell
}
```

I register the cell with

```
fileprivate func registerCollectionView() {
    collectionView.register(profCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: profID)
  //  collectionView.register(profCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "profCell")
}
```

and then inside my view didload

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerCollectionView() 
}
```

is there sonething I did wrong? Im not sure why this still crashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things going on here. First, you have commented out the line that sets the reuse identifier for the cell. You need to uncomment this line:

```
 collectionView.register(profCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "profCell")
```

Second, when you are creating your cell you are using the wrong reuse identifier. You need to use "profCell" instead of "Cell".

> **Edit (dahiya_boy) :** I register XIB's in below way and its also valid

**How to register CollectionViewCell**

```
 colView.register(UINib(nibName: "ColViewCellXib", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ColViewCellXib")
```

And,

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColViewCellXib", for: indexPath) as! ColViewCellXib
    return cell
}
```

**How to register TableViewViewCell**

```
 tblView.register(UINib(nibName: "TblCellXib", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TblCellXib")
```

And,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TblCellXib") as! TblCellXib
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Why not downvote the question, I see you guys downvoting everywhere. This answer was answered many times.

Comment: woah now. I had the correct code, i just had a simple mistake. I would rather delete it, but if anyone in the future had the same issue here they go.